# Temporarily remove an object from a managed object context

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Imagine I have three `NSManagedObject`s, each with a single string field named `content`, represented in the UI by a `UITextField`. The `content` field must not be blank for a successful save. However, I would like to be able to save the managed object context as soon as the user has finished editing a single field. So if just one field has been filled in, calling `save` on the managed object context would save only that field's corresponding managed object, skipping the other two.

The way I currently have things set up, the `save` call fails because the `content` field of the other two managed objects is empty (string length == 0). It occurs to me that a potential solution would be to temporarily remove these objects from the managed object context, call `save`, and then re-insert them back into the managed object context. While it appears that the `NSManagedObjectContext` method `insertObject:` could achieve the re-insertion part of this approach, I don't see a method for initially removing the object from the managed object context.

How would I ultimately achieve this?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to save the context straight away. iOS is keeping the information in memory and saving only persists it to the database. However the information is still available in the specific context without saving. Another way would be to remove the constraint that the content text field needs to be filled.

Comment: Why don't you create each managed object when the user has obtained the focus on the text field? In this way you will have only the objects you need...

Comment: in addition I would not rely on Core Data validation...do it yourself. Much better!

Comment: @flexaddicted - I want to allow the user to switch from one textfield to the next, even if they haven't added text to the one they're switching from. And what's wrong with relying on Core Data validation as it pertains to my question?

Comment: Lorenzo Boaro's comment is spot on.  This question is a classic illustration of why I *never* use Core Data's *validation* features.